# Rails: Looking up foreign key id using virtual attribute failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app allows users to add words from a master words table into their own custom list. So, a word list contains multiple custom words each of which link to a master word.

In my view, I have a field called word_text (virtual attribute) where I let users enter a word, and in my model I am trying to look up the master_word_id and set it on the custom word table. I am unable to access the @word_text value in the model. I always seem to get an error that the master word is a required field (because the look up is failing).

```
class CustomWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :master_word_id, :word_list_id, :word_text
  attr_accessor :word_text

  belongs_to :word_list
  belongs_to :master_word
  validates :word_list, presence: true
  validates :master_word, presence: true

  before_validation :set_master_word

  private 

  def set_master_word
    logger.debug "Received word text #{@word_text}"
    _mw_id = nil
    if !@word_text.nil?
      master_word = MasterWord.find_word(@word_text)
      if master_word.nil?
    errors.add("#{@word_text} is not a valid word")
      else  
    _mw_id = master_word.id
      end  
    end
    self.master_word_id = _mw_id  
  end

end
```

I sincerely appreciate any suggestions as to how I can set the value of the master_word_id correctly.

Comment: If `set_master_words`'s logging indicates `@word_text` is empty, we'd need to se how are you *setting* `word_text`. Also, you don't need to use `@word_text` inside the model. Just use `word_text`.

Comment: B.T.W - `if !@word_text.nil?` can be replaced with `if @word_text`. And `if master_word.nil?` can be replaced with `unless master_word`

Comment: Thanks meagar, @user2503775. I made the changes, and as you can see I am newbie to Rails. Learning something new everyday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to fix:

```
class CustomWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :master_word_id, :word_list_id, :word_text
  attr_accessor :word_text

  belongs_to :word_list
  belongs_to :master_word
  validates :word_list, presence: true
  #validates :master_word, presence: true <= This will always throw error
  validates :word_text, presence: true
  validates :master_word_id, presence: true

  before_validation :set_master_word

  private 

  def set_master_word
    logger.debug "Received word text #{self.word_text}"
    self.master_word_id = MasterWord.find_by_word_text(self.word_text).id
  end

end
```

Not sure if it will work because I don't know the rest of your app but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @CV-Gate. That helped, and I see the word_text now. I don't see the error message now though for an invalid word, and the master_word_id is getting set to nil/null for invalid words. How do I stop the execution and return an error message to the users?